# Ball properties with different metrics

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, metric-spaces

I am stuck with the following intuitive question:

Let $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open bounded set (with standard Euclidean topology). Let $g_1$ be the induced Euclidean metric from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $M$ and let $g_2$ be another (arbitrary) metric on $M$ such that $g_2$ induces the same topology on $M$.

Question:

For any $\delta >0$, is it always true that there is $\epsilon >0$ such that
$$B_{g_1}(x,\epsilon) \subset B_{g_2}(x,\delta),\forall x \in M?$$

Here $B_{g_1}(x,\epsilon):=\{y\in M: d_{g_1}(x,y) <\epsilon\}$ and $B_{g_2}(x,\epsilon):=\{y\in M: d_{g_2}(x,y) <\epsilon\}$ are open balls of radius $\epsilon$ w.r.t. each metrics.

I think this is not true but I couldn't find a counterexample.

Comment: This would be true if $g_2$ were induced by a norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true: Take $n=1, M=(0,1)$ and $g_2(x)=|\frac  1 x-\frac 1 y|$. Then $g_2$ has the same open sets as $g_1$ and the inclusion you have written says that $\frac  1 x$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ which is false.

Comment: Thanks. Very good answer.